# PHP: glob function within a glob function to create populating grid w/images

Tags: php, image, function, glob

I've been having alittle difficulty with this problem and wanted to know if anyone has a solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c34x0.jpg

In this image above is what I'm working on. These are item blocks, of which each one represents a directory. In each directory will display thumbnail images of those directories, with the title(ex. SAMPLE_2), category(ex. Data Analytics), short desc(in yellow), long desc(not pictured), and skills.

Now the images on the top will be read, displayed, and go along the flexslider carousel.
And don't mind the borders, they are there to see where I am.

Below are my variables, the $img is the variable in question to get to work, I'll explain later.

```
$base = "projects"; //main project directory
$categ = "*"; //category for each type of project
$pro = "*"; //project directory

$img = "images/img/*"; //thumbnail project images directory
```

So as you can see below, I have a glob function for each $base/$categ/$pro that will pass as $folder, it prints out the images associated with that project.The code below is only the thumbnail images and not the project description section. (thats fine)

```
foreach(glob("$base/$categ/$pro") as $folder)
{
    <ul>
     echo "<li><img src='$folder/images/img/pic1.jpg'/></li>";
     echo "<li><img src='$folder/images/img/pic2.jpg'/></li>";
    </ul>
}
```

This works fine as this, but now I want to pass a function that will read from inside the images/img directory and print all images inside that directory.

So using

```
$img = "/images/img/*";
```

I'm looking to accomplish this

```
echo "<li><img src='$folder/$img'/></li>";
```

Without having to add another li. I've tried:

```
if(glob($img.'{jpg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE)){
  echo "<li><img src='$folder/$img'/></li>";
};
```

But doesn't work. Tried "foreach" instead of "if" but nothing appears. So is it possible for there to be a glob function inside a glob function. And if so, how could I get the images to show up? (Each project would be different, so each would display different images of course.)

Thanks and I will be updating.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!!!

So i used:

```
$img = "images/img/*";
```

Made an adjustment to the first glob:

```
foreach(glob("$base/$categ/$pro/") as $folder)
```

Made a new variable called "images"

```
$images = (glob($folder.$img.'{jpg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE));
```

And resulted in this:

```
$base = "projects"; 
$categ = "*"; 
$pro = "*"; 

$img = "images/img/*"; //thumbnail project images directory

foreach(glob("$base/$categ/$pro/") as $folder)
{
   $images = (glob($folder.$img.'{jpg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE));
    foreach($images as $image) {
    <ul>
    echo "<li><img src='$image'/></li>";
    </ul>
     };
};
```